# Setting up Kafka Connect, cannot rename group ID

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using this Github repo and folder path I found: https://github.com/entechlog/kafka-examples/tree/master/kafka-connect-standalone

The issue I am having is that, as a matter of access control, I *must* specify my group ID by adding a prefix to it, let's call it `abc-`. When I build this Docker image, I check my logs and I can see that the group ID ends up being `connect-bq-sink-connector`, which I am assuming is a concatenation of the word `connect-` along with the variable `CONNECTOR_NAME` seen in the docker-compose file. When I change the connector name variable, my group ID also changes (but the `connect-` prefix always remains). You will also see a variable called `CONNECT_GROUP_ID` in the docker-compose file. This variable appears to have absolutely no effect on the Kafka connect instance. The Docker logs give this (in this order):

`WARN The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:380)`

and then later...

...

`group.id = connect-bq-sink-connector`

The final error, which is mostly unimportant as I know it is due to lack of permissions, is simply:

```
[2021-12-03 22:37:32,775] INFO [bq-sink-connector|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-bq-sink-connector-0, groupId=connect-bq-sink-connector] FindCoordinator request hit fatal exception (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:260)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access Group: connect-bq-sink-connector
```

and so two things: I cannot figure out why the word `connect-` is being prefixed every time to the resulting group ID, and also why the variable CONNECT_GROUP_ID seems to not function at all.

I thought maybe the image is forcibly hard coding `connect-` in front. I tried running this by changing line 50 in the docker compose file from `image: entechlog/cp-kafka-connect${CONFLUENT_VERSION_TAG}` to `image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0` and it changed nothing.

What is causing this prefix to be added, and how can I override this? I can keep the word `connect` there if necessary, but I simply need to add my prefix `abc-` in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change connect group id, add environment variable name `CONNECTOR_` properties section under the service `kafka-connect` and set a value you want.

The github example starting steps as follows.

- In file `docker/Dockerfile`, a startup command is `/etc/confluent/docker/run` and you cant find the file in `docker/include/etc/confluent/docker`.
- Start a container with simple step `configure` and `launch` in the `docker/include/etc/confluent/docker/run` file.
- In file `docker/include/etc/confluent/docker/configure`, Check mandatory environment variables such as `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`, `CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER`, `CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER`... are set, and call templating function with `kafka-connect-standalone.properties.template` and `kafka-connect.properties.template`.

So if there is a configuration that you want to add to the `kafka-connect-standalone.properties` file, you must specify an environment variable starting with `CONNECTOR_`.

You can find all configuration for kafka connect in the following link.

> https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs

Comment: I will give this a try, but I thought I had already attempted it. As for the Dockerfile, is it even being used, since we are using the confluent image?

Comment: No I use exact the same example. The image in the example, I think it is from `confluentinc/cp-server-connect-base:6.2.1`.

Comment: I still see in the logs: `groupId=connect-bq-sink-connector` so the 'connect-' is still there...

Comment: Your points make sense to me except I still don't understand how to specify the group ID and override this `connect-` prefix in the group ID (check logs, `connect-` is prefixed to whatever I call the connector name).

Comment: I missed a starting step. There may be no bug. I finally find document for BigQueryConnector, and there may be no way to change groupId.

> https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/kafka_connect_bigquery_config.html#kafka-connect-bigquery-config

I will edit the answer.

Comment: I looked through the doc, how can you tell that the group ID cannot be changed? Certainly it can be set to something, but how do you know we can't remove the prefix?

Comment: I finally find the answer! There is no way to change the "group.id". Check the following source code from apache kafka.  https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/util/SinkUtils.java

Comment: That last comment is the actual answer. I'm not sure why you included details about the converters and such. `CONNECTOR_GROUP_ID`  doesn't do anything for Connect standalone, and is not necessarily a property for any specific connector class

Answer (score 2):

The Sink Connector consumer group id prefix cannot be changed

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4400

`CONNECT_GROUP_ID` is only applicable for Kafka Connect distributed mode *clustering*, not consumers, which the Confluent images use. I don't see any benefit of using the linked image that runs standalone since that would fail to be fault tolerant or scalable (the Connect configs and status are stored in an ephemeral filesystem rather than back in Kafka)

Comment: I run it standalone as a POC to test locally. If I run this in distributed mode in a cloud environment, will `CONNECT_GROUP_ID` also use the same class `SinkUtils` and its method `consumerGroupId` to append `connect-` in front?

Comment: Standalone and distributed roughly use the same internal classes, yes

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to change the group id for the kafka sink connector.

`consumer group id` is hardcoded and prefixed with `connect-`.

```java
package org.apache.kafka.connect.util;

public final class SinkUtils {

    private SinkUtils() {}

    public static String consumerGroupId(String connector) {
        return "connect-" + connector;
    }

}
```

Ref. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/util/SinkUtils.java